# Using OCMock with Facebook

Tags: facebook-login, ocmock, kif, facebook

I am new to the concepts of UI Automation Testing so OCMock is decently foreign for me. I was having trouble approaching how I would mock a login. I'm also using the KIF framework which allows me to access things in a view with accessibility labels. However, I don't know how to access the accessibility labels of the view presented when Facebook opens a UIWebView so I'm attempting to mock a FBLoginView class and then mock a login to bypass this problem I'm facing.

Please help by either providing me with knowledge on getting through this with the KIF framework, or knowledge concerning how I would approach using OCMock to mock the FBLoginView class. Thank you

Comment: Do you basically want documentation on how to use OCMock?

Comment: Essentially yes, I would, but the documentation located with the website is somewhat confusing and slightly unrelated to my specific needs.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "mock a login to bypass this problem"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for making my question so vague but I have answered it myself. I believe the proper way to mock a Facebook login is to mock the FBLoginView Class. Then Mock the Protocol. Call the protocol method "loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:" and pass in the mocked class.

```
        //mock class       
        id classMock = OCMClassMock([FBLoginView class]);
        //mock delegate
        id protocolMock = OCMProtocolMock(@protocol(FBLoginViewDelegate));
        //mock delegate method
        [protocolMock loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:classMock];
        //verify delegate method called.
        OCMVerify([protocolMock loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:classMock]);
```